# Multiple IDE's in a software development team

Tags: eclipse, swing, netbeans, ide, collaboration

My team's about to begin development on an application with a Swing client and an EJB Back end.

I'm thinking of standardizing on using Netbeans for developing the Swing portion because of it's very user friendly swing designer functionality but still make use of Eclipse for the rest.

Just wondering if anybody has done this and if so how well did it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is going to be "it depends."

If you have relatively experienced engineers that can manage their own IDE configuration, then I would say let them use whatever they want.  I worked on a project where in the web side I was in netbeans, and in the rest of the modules I was in eclipse.  It worked ok, but there wasn't really any set "standard" because everyone was experienced enough to be able to manage their IDE.

In a setting where you have less experienced engineers then having a single IDE is great because it'll reduce the amount of time the team leads have to spend keeping the junior developers up and running, and in that case, it would be much easier to maintain a single development environment instead of multiple.

In no case would I check in the project files generated by netbeans or eclipse.  While it may seem to be nice at the start to get people up and running, when anyone wants to customize their setup at all you suddenly have a battle of configuration files in your source control, and that stinks.

Comment: @Joel - Have you used the GUI Designer in NetBeans on a project? It enables the kind of rapid prototyping and productivity in terms of WYSIWYG that was previously only available to Visual Studio users. There's a big difference between doing a web project and a swing project. For web-based or server-side development I would agree with you that it depends, but because of the Swing requirement I think it is fairly clear that standardizing on NetBeans will save enormous amounts of layout and prototyping time.

Comment: I haven't done any desktop java development in ages.  I was answering the question more from the view of using different IDEs in different aspects of a project.  Each IDE definitely has it's strengths and weaknesses, and standardizing on one will help a less experienced team for sure, but like vi vs. emacs, for a more experienced developer you may be getting into a more religious than technical area ;)

Answer (score 1):

**You should standardize on NetBeans for a Swing Project**

Yes you should standardize on NetBeans if you are doing a Java Swing Client IDE. Otherwise the entire team will not be able to take advantage of the excellent GUI designer in NetBeans. Moreover they may break the work done by the members using the NetBeans GUI tool.

I have worked on a project where we used 3 or 4 IDEs to develop a multi-million dollar Swing Client. There was a major productivity loss because NetBeans was not used by the entire team.

Theoretically you could allow multiple IDEs for the backend work as it doesn't matter as much, but it is very nice to beable to use the NetBeans builds and to fully integrate everything in a single IDE.

Based on my experience not doing what you are proposing, and on my experience in being able to do rapid development in Swing with NetBeans I would say definitely lock in on NetBeans.

Answer (score -1):

While developer freedom is great, you are sacrificing a lot of functionality by not standardizing on a single IDE. Project metadata often doesn't mix well and you really do want to put the metadata in source control. If you are getting battle of configuration file changes between developers, you are doing it wrong.

You may want to consider WindowBuilder plugin for Eclipse rather than going to NetBeans for Swing development.

http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder

Comment: I strongly disagree with checking in IDE based project metadata, but perhaps that is because I work in maven based projects and creating the project is simply a matter of running eclipse:eclipse or using an eclipse plugin (or netbeans which has great built-in maven support)

Comment: To each their own. Relying on Maven limits what you can do with your projects in Eclipse as you are forced to stay in the box supported by Maven, but maybe the box is ok with you... I strongly recommend not mixing commandline build solutions like Maven and IDEs. They serve different purposes and mixing them limits functionality of both.